# npm not working not found

Tags: npm, ubuntu-14.04

Im trying to use npm on Ubuntu 14.04.

An example I use:

```
sudo npm install pm2 -g --unsafe-perm

/usr/local/bin/node: 2: /usr/local/bin/node: D?F=: not found
/usr/local/bin/node: 3: /usr/local/bin/node: :$?#ZBh: not found
/usr/local/bin/node: 3: /usr/local/bin/node: ?=?E??2?: not found
/usr/local/bin/node: 5: /usr/local/bin/node: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
sadmin@tigger:/usr/local/bin$ /usr/local/bin/node: 3: /usr/local/bin/node: /usr/local/bin/node: 3: /usr/l?8?#2R3?8?/?FE?: not found
4?ImJ?9: not found
/usr/local/bin/node: 1: /usr/local/bin/node: ELF: not found
```

Comment: Is nodejs and npm installed?

Comment: After they are installed do:

Comment: As root ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

Comment: Hi Roger both are installed double checked both are present in /usr/bin/ tried doing the symbolic link and I get the same issue

Comment: Doh Symbolic link to npm was incorrect